# How to read the updated Property value in Java?

Tags: java

I am getting each values in the Property value in a Static variable. I have a scenario in my automation that i have to update one of the value in the property file and use that updated value further in the code.

Since the values are in static variable new value is not loaded and only old values are used.

Is there any way to get the new value

Comment: Please provide us [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't think that variable being static has anything to do with your problem. You can change static variable just like any non-static.

Answer (score 0):

It requires a mechanism to watch the changes in file and update your variables. Since you didn't provide any details, answer cannot be more helpful.

Other thing to watch for is that if you initialize some objects with the values from your properties (like database connection), than those objects would need also to be reinitialized after every change.